# Dynamically create javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have below code in which i need to create a dynamic object

```
let response = {};
const process = (key, value) => {
if (key == FieldMapping[key]) {
    response = {
        ...response,
        key : value
    }
    console.log(key + " : " + value);
}
}
```

In the above code, i want to pass `key` as property of new object and `value` as value and keep all the previous added property and its value but it's not persisting the previously added property. Also `FieldMapping[key] : value` is giving compilation error .What's wrong here?

Comment: `response = { ...response, [key]: value}`

Comment: What is `FieldMapping` here and what values have you passed when calling the `process` function?

Comment: var new_obj={}; new_obj[key]=value

Comment: @connexo That is syntax error, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current code will keep creating/overwriting a `key` property. What you instead want is a property with the name of the string contained in `key`. You achieve this using the bracket property notation:

```
response = { ...response, [key]: value}
```

See it work:

```js
const key = 'foo', value = 'bar';
let response = { baz: true };
response = { ...response, [key]: value };
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `response` object:

```
response = {...response}

response[key] = value
```

---

`FieldMapping[key] : value` should be `FieldMapping[key] = value`